# problem with logic in django code. read data from redis and database

Tags: python, django, redis, pytest

I have this django code and it take data from redis by inscode and return. if redis is down it should jump out of try,expect block and read data from database (postgresql).

```
class GetOrderBook(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        # get parameters
        inscode = None
        if 'i' in request.GET:
            inscode = request.GET['i']

        if inscode != None:
            try:
                #raise ('disabling redis!')
                r_handle = redisconnection

                data = r_handle.get(inscode)

                if data != None:
                    return Response(200)
                else:
                    print('not found in cache')
            except BaseException as err:
                print(err)
            orderbook = OrderBook.objects.filter(
                symbol__inscode=inscode).order_by('rownum')
            if len(orderbook) > 0:
                data = OrderBookSer(orderbook, many=True).data
                data_formatted = {'buynum': [0]*5, 'buyvol': [0]*5, 'buyprice': [
                    0]*5, 'sellnum': [0]*5, 'sellvol': [0]*5, 'sellprice': [0]*5}
                

                return Response(data_formatted, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            else:
                return Response({'Bad Request'}, status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        return Response({'Bad Request'}, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

but problem is that it not reading from database also I write this test for it to return 200 if you read data. but when redis is down it dont read data and return 404 to me .

```
def test_redis_function(self, api_client, test_user):
    url = self.url
    api_client.force_authenticate(user=test_user)  
    
    response = api_client.get(url, {'i': '2400322364771558'}) 
    assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK
```

I would be more than happy if you help me

Comment: This means that the `len(orderbook)` == 0 as 404 comes from there. Which indicates that your query isn't correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pytest with django creates new test-database for your tests and it looks like you forgot to create object of class OrderBook before start this test.
Add setup function for you test or just add something like

```
symbol = Symbol.objects.create(inscode=2400322364771558)
OrderBook.objects.create(symbol=symbol)
```

before api_client call.

But better practice - use Django Factory Boy https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/orms.html